# VBA to generate permanent Controlls in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

**Situation:**
I download Attachments from Outlook and import them into Access tables based on a few criteria.

For example, I download following files:
SenderA_A_Timestamp.csv, SenderA_B_Timestamp.csv, SenderB_C_Timestamp.csv, SenderC_A_Timestamp.csv and loads more.

Now I have made a form where the user can, for example, select all type C CSV-Files since a date or just all types, since a certain date.

[image]

Cluster, Hosts and Volume represent the File types. The datetime indicates when it was updated last. Cl_Import, Hosts_Import and Volume_Import are the import specification needed for the different files.

**Problem:** 
I now want to add a new type, for example, under Volume and want to have it stay there when I open the Form the next time.

*Software:*
-Microsoft Access 2016
-SQL queries
-Outlook 2016
-VBA

Comment: It's a database, you can save anything you want. But unless you give a lot more details, we cannot help you.

Comment: I updated it, hope you know what I mean

Comment: You could create your own switchboard type form (similar to the one the wizard creates).  When finished you just add your new type to the underlying table and it will appear on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table called `SwitchboardItems`.
Add these fields:

- ItemNumber (Numeric, Primary Key)
- ItemText (Text)
- Command (Numeric)
- Argument (Text)

`ItemNumber` should be sequential (use AutoNum if you want).
`ItemText` is the text as it will appear on the form.
`Command` indicate what to do when the button is pressed.
`Argument` is anything pertinent to that option (such as the file name to be opened).
[image]

Create a blank `Continuous` form.
The Record Source is:
`SELECT * FROM SwitchboardItems WHERE [ItemNumber]>0 ORDER BY [ItemNumber];`
`ItemNumber 0` is the heading for the menu so is ignored in the record source.
Turn `Data Entry`, `Allow Additions`, `Allow Deletions`, `Allow Edits` and `Allow Filters` to `No` on the `Data` tab in the form properties

Add a command button and a textbox to the `Detail` section of your form.
Give the button the name of `Option1` and the textbox `OptionLabel1`.
The `Control Source` for the textbox is `ItemText`.
Add a label to the `Form Header` name it `Label1`.

Add the below code to the `Form_Open` event.  It places the menu heading in the form header:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    Me.Label1.Caption = DLookup("ItemText", "SwitchboardItems", "[ItemNumber]=0")
    Me.Requery

End Sub
```

Add this code to the form module:

```
Private Sub Option_Click()

    Select Case Command
        Case 1
            'Add code to set references to Excel, etc...
            'Dim wrkbk As Object
            'Set wrkbk = workbooks.Open([Argument])
        Case 2
            MsgBox [Argument]
        Case 3
            DoCmd.OpenForm [Argument], acNormal
        Case 4
            DoCmd.OpenReport [Argument], acViewNormal
        Case 5

        Case 6
            DoCmd.Close
        Case 7
            DoCmd.OpenQuery [Argument]
        Case 8
    End Select

End Sub
```

Each Case statement reflects the `Command` value in the `SwitchboardItems` table and you should code what you want each to do (open workbooks, close the database, run SQL, etc).

Finally, add this code to the click events for the Option1 textbox and command button:

```
Private Sub Option1_Click()
    Option_Click
End Sub

Private Sub OptionLabel1_Click()
    Option_Click
End Sub
```

Your finished form will look similar to this (I've clicked *Other_Import* button which displays a message box as *Command* is 2):
[image]

**NB:**  There's a lot more you could add to this - the last updated time as an extra field in the table for example.

Comment: Are you an access-god? Thank you very much :)

Comment: I can't be - very much an atheist. :)

Comment: So? Would God believe in a super god?

Comment: That would never work as there'd be the whole does super god believe in super-super god and eventually you'll get some kind of overflow error and the universe will vanish in a puff of logic (pretty sure the last half of that sentence is a Douglas Adams quote).

Comment: Haha^^ I like you, guy