# How to navigate to a form based on a comb box selection in Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I'm creating a form for my Microsoft Access database.  I have a combo box, and I need it to navigate to the form based on which item the user clicks.

How would I do this?  I know it requires some VBA code, but none of the methods I have tried have worked thus far.

The form I am trying to navigate to is called "Forms_Reports"

My current code:

```
Private Sub Combo0_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.Combo0.Value = 1 Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Forms_Reports", acNormal
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to post more info eg. the code you have already tried.

Comment: You could try a switchboard if it's just a navigation form.  I think Access still has a switchboard wizard, but failing that I give an explanation here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45011763/vba-to-generate-permanent-controlls-in-microsoft-access/45013790#45013790

Answer (score 1):

Your code is basically okay, but you can't combine it in a single line. Also, I'm guessing your form is really just named "Reports". You don't include the Form_ prefix displayed in the project window.  Try this:

```
Private Sub Combo0_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.Combo0.Value = 1 Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Reports", acNormal
    End If
End Sub
```